# What's the meaning of あったかもね?

Tags: meaning

This is the first time I have seen this and I don't know its meaning or what does in the sentence

> 素質はなんとなく**あったかもね**

Best Regards

Comment: This is on the border, but I suspect that this question might get closed for being off topic..
See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Also see: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/22352

Answer (score 2, accepted):

あった is just the past tense of the common verb ある, to exist. In this case, it's part of the expression 素質がある, meaning to "have the potential" for something. (eg. 彼は科学者の素質がある "He has the makings of a scientist!")

かも is a short form of かもしれない, the common way of expressing possibility. It can usually be translated as "maybe", "perhaps", "might have" etc.

And ね is the common sentence-ending particle indicating a "tag question" or an expectation of agreement. It can be often be translated as something like "right?" or "you know" (if it needs translating at all). When used together with かも, it often indicates the speaker is tentatively agreeing with a point someone else has made.

So to put it all together, the sentence means something like "Maybe he did sort of have the potential." (What exactly he had the potential for - and indeed whether the subject is actually a "he" at all - is a mystery without more context.)